# How could I start up a specialize main-class to run a jar package?

Tags: java, spring

I had build/package two main-class into one jar package, and I would like to specialize one of them to start up according to my needs.
For sample, there is `com.sample.MainClassOne` and `com.sample.bat.MainClassTwo` in `sample.jar`. `com.sample.MainClassOne` will always startup when I run `java -jar sample.jar`. And sometimes I would like to start up `com.sample.bat.MainClassTwo`, how should I?

Comment: Why not pass command-line arguments to decide which implementation to use instead? `if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("two")) { MainTwo.main(args); } else { MainOne.main(args);  }`. Pretty easy solution, although  theres far better designs

Answer (score 1):

A runnable jar file is still a normal jar file, you can do:

```
java -cp sample.jar com.sample.bat.MainClassTwo
```

(in addition to being able to do `java -jar sample.jar` to run `com.sample.MainClassOne` )

Comment: `java -cp` print a error : could not found or load Main-Class com.sample.MainClassTwo

Comment: When you do a `jar tf sample.jar`, does it contain a file `com/sample/MainClassTwo.class` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can select which is the main class of a jar while you are creating runnable jar.
You can see it in MANIFEST.MF file inside jar file.
Change the Main-Class key entry to your desired class name